# How to give url.action for ajax url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

How to give url.action for ajax url ?

my url like this  url: "CheckSiteNameExist"

```
$("#SiteName").change(function () {
        var subRegionId = $("#SubRegion").val();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "CheckSiteNameExist",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ subRegionId: parseInt(subRegionId), siteName: value }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'False') {
                    $('#isSiteExist').show();
                } else {
                    $('#isSiteExist').hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

Not always went absolute path how to set relative path to my controller in url.action ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `CheckSiteNameExist` with `@Url.Action(...)`?

Comment: Does the absolute URL work?

Comment: what do you mean by url is "checksitenameexist" ,url must be something like that "/checksitenameexist" or "http://remoteserveurl/checksitenameexists"

Comment: start the url with `/` in order to make it relative :)

Comment: @martinezjc - you could not be more wrong :) That's an absolute URL. The leading `/` indicates the root folder.

Comment: :( actually you're right, sorry.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like this if **CheckSiteNameExists** is your controller name:

`url:"@Url.Action("Index","CheckSiteNameExists")"`

First parameter is action name and second parameter is controller name.